# Sort dataframe row while preserving columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe something like shown below:

```
         U1      U2      U3                                                      
U1       1.0     0.0     0.2 
U2       0.4     1.0     0.0
U3       0.0     0.45    1.0
```

Here, U1, U2 and U3 are indexes and column headers.
I want to sort the values in each row and then select top 20 from each row.
However, after sorting, I also need to know that a particular value is coming from which row and column.
eg, if I sort each row individually, I will get:

```
         U2      U3      U1                                                      
U1       0.0     0.2     1.0
```

for 1st row

```
         U3      U1      U2                                                     
U2       0.0     0.4     1.0
```

for 2nd row

```
         U1      U2      U3                                                      
U3       0.0     0.45    1.0
```

for 3rd row.

However, the order for columns are now different for each of the row.
Is there an efficient way/data-structure (preferably a dataframe or numpy array) where I can aggregate this sorted information ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this could help, where you can get the result with single sorting!

```
pd.DataFrame(list(df.apply(lambda x : sorted((x,c) for x,c in zip(x,df.columns)),axis=1)),
             index=df.index)

         0           1              2
U1  (0.0, 'U2') (0.2, 'U3')     (1.0, 'U1')
U2  (0.0, 'U3') (0.4, 'U1')     (1.0, 'U2')
U3  (0.0, 'U1') (0.45, 'U2')    (1.0, 'U3')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`numpy.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) for positions and then reorder values of columns and by values of DataFrame:

```
pos = df.values.argsort(axis=1)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.columns[pos], index=df.index)
print (df1)
     0   1   2
U1  U2  U3  U1
U2  U3  U1  U2
U3  U1  U2  U3

arr1 = df.columns.values[pos]
print (arr1)
[['U2' 'U3' 'U1']
 ['U3' 'U1' 'U2']
 ['U1' 'U2' 'U3']]
```

For change positions by `pos` use:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.values[np.arange(len(df))[:, None], pos], index=df.index)
print (df2)
      0     1    2
U1  0.0  0.20  1.0
U2  0.0  0.40  1.0
U3  0.0  0.45  1.0

arr2 = df.values[np.arange(len(df))[:, None], pos]
print (arr2)
[[0.   0.2  1.  ]
 [0.   0.4  1.  ]
 [0.   0.45 1.  ]]
```